# Get Extra argument 'method' in call when was handling API Calling ,

Tags: swift, alamofire

Now I use Alamofire latest version 4.7.3 and using swift 4.1 I got error **Get Extra argument** I don't know what happening

```
func serviceHandling(){
    let url : String = "http://1.1.11.15:8080/f/api/getLoginDetails"
    var params: NSDictionary = ["userName" : "test1234" , "password":"test1234" ,"gcmRegistrationId":"test","deviceType":"iPhone"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
        { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `HTTPMethod.post` as the parameter? Does it build when you comment the Alamofire request out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `params` as `NSDictionary` in this line

```
var params: NSDictionary = ["userName" : "test1234" , "password":"test1234" ,"gcmRegistrationId":"test","deviceType":"iPhone"]
```

Alamofire request expects parameters of type `Parameter` which is in fact of type `[String: Any]`. All you have to do is to declare your params with this type

```
var params: [String: Any] = ["userName" : "test1234" , "password":"test1234" ,"gcmRegistrationId":"test","deviceType":"iPhone"]
```

Comment: @user3217753 Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved